# Text position in CMFCPropertyGridCtrl

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, cmfcpropertygridctrl

When editing (or clicking with `AllowEdit` set to `false`) the text is moved left:

[image]

But Visual Studio itself does not suffer from this issue:

[image]

The text stays exactly where it is before getting focus.

How do we achieve this?

I should clarify that my `CMFCPropertyGridEditProperty` is doing this:

```
CWnd* CMFCPropertyGridEditProperty::CreateInPlaceEdit(CRect rectEdit, BOOL& bDefaultFormat)
{
    CEdit *pEdit = (CEdit*)CMFCPropertyGridProperty::CreateInPlaceEdit(rectEdit, bDefaultFormat);
    CString strClassName;

    // Note that CreateInPlaceEdit can also return a CMFCMaskedEdit.
    // But we are only supporting the CEdit.
    GetClassName(pEdit->GetSafeHwnd(), strClassName.GetBuffer(_MAX_PATH), _MAX_PATH);
    strClassName.ReleaseBuffer();

    if (pEdit != NULL && strClassName == _T("Edit"))
        pEdit->SetLimitText(m_iTextLimit);

    return (CWnd*)pEdit;
}
```

But it does the same even if I use `CMFCPropertyGridProperty`.

To answer question 1 in the comments, I use the `COLeVariant` overload:

```
auto AddProperty = [&](CMFCPropertyGridProperty* pMeeting, CString strLabel, CString strValue)
    {
        if (pMeeting != nullptr)
        {
            COleVariant vString(strValue);
            //CMFCPropertyGridEditProperty* pProperty = nullptr;
            CMFCPropertyGridProperty* pProperty = nullptr;

            //pProperty = new CMFCPropertyGridEditProperty(strLabel, vString, L"", 0, 50);
            pProperty = new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(strLabel, vString, L"", 0);
            if (pProperty != nullptr)
            {
                pProperty->AllowEdit(false);
                pMeeting->AddSubItem(pProperty);
            }
        }
    };
```

To answer question 2, the answer is no. This is a property grid control dragged onto a `CDialog` in the resource IDE.

---

If I create a Visual Studio style MDI then the built-in prop grid on the right behaves. Click a cell and text does not move.

Add a prop grid to the about dialog and display about window:

[image: about]

Get same behaviour as for me in my dialog app.

Comment: Can't see this behaviour in my many text-value `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl`-derived classes. What overload of the `SetValue(...)` function are you using? I mean, it takes a `_variant` argument but that has many different constructors. I use a `const wchar_t*` argument, generally.

Comment: ... and is the property grid in a (docked) pane of a `CMFCFrameWindow`-derived parent?

Comment: @AdrianMole If I create a MDI appl with Visual Studio style, so that a prop grid is automatically in a dock pain then THAT behaves. But not my `CDialog` app.

Comment: What happens if you call the `AdjustLayout()` member of the parent `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl` after making your changes in the edit/click handler?

Comment: @AdrianMole Please see my answer. Welcome your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working solution (for me on my PC) but I would still like more information about this matter.

I decided to use my `CMFCPropertyGridEditProperty` class after all with one minor tweak to `CreateInPlaceEdit`:

```
CWnd* CMFCPropertyGridEditProperty::CreateInPlaceEdit(CRect rectEdit, BOOL& bDefaultFormat)
{
    rectEdit.OffsetRect(3, 0);
    CEdit *pEdit = (CEdit*)CMFCPropertyGridProperty::CreateInPlaceEdit(rectEdit, bDefaultFormat);
    CString strClassName;

    // Note that CreateInPlaceEdit can also return a CMFCMaskedEdit.
    // But we are only supporting the CEdit.
    GetClassName(pEdit->GetSafeHwnd(), strClassName.GetBuffer(_MAX_PATH), _MAX_PATH);
    strClassName.ReleaseBuffer();

    if (pEdit != nullptr && strClassName == L"Edit")
        pEdit->SetLimitText(m_iTextLimit);

    return (CWnd*)pEdit;
}
```

I inserted this line to offset the rectangle:

```
rectEdit.OffsetRect(3, 0);
```

Now the text does not shift when I click on a property.

---

Things I have learned:

- Using a property grid inside a `CDialog` causing the moving of the text.

Things I am curious about:

- What is causing this issue?
- Will offsetting by 3 pixels be correct for all PC configurations?
- Can this issue be prevented to avoid the need of this workaround?

---

After more thinking on the matter I have come up with:

```
CWnd* CMFCPropertyGridEditProperty::CreateInPlaceEdit(CRect rectEdit, BOOL& bDefaultFormat)
{
    rectEdit.OffsetRect(::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXDLGFRAME), 0);
    CEdit *pEdit = (CEdit*)CMFCPropertyGridProperty::CreateInPlaceEdit(rectEdit, bDefaultFormat);
    CString strClassName;

    // Note that CreateInPlaceEdit can also return a CMFCMaskedEdit.
    // But we are only supporting the CEdit.
    GetClassName(pEdit->GetSafeHwnd(), strClassName.GetBuffer(_MAX_PATH), _MAX_PATH);
    strClassName.ReleaseBuffer();

    if (pEdit != nullptr && strClassName == L"Edit")
        pEdit->SetLimitText(m_iTextLimit);

    return (CWnd*)pEdit;
}
```

I have adjust the first line of code to:

```
rectEdit.OffsetRect(::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXDLGFRAME), 0);
```

I now use [`::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXDLGFRAME)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics). To quote:

> The thickness of the frame around the perimeter of a window that has a caption but is not sizable, in pixels. `SM_CXFIXEDFRAME` is the height of the horizontal border, and `SM_CYFIXEDFRAME` is the width of the vertical border.
>
> This value is the same as `SM_CXDLGFRAME`.

I have reported this issue:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Using-CMFCPropertyGridCtrl-inside-a-CDia/10565729